# displaying the result of my join statement in angularjs and laravel 5.1 with ngResource

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, laravel-5

im having problem in displaying with my populated data in angularjs as my frontend and laravel as my backend, the query seems to be okay 'cause it did response in a right way maybe my way of diplaying it or the way it should be done.. this my snippet so far

**angularjs**

```
Transaction.get(function(data){
            $scope.transactions = data.transactions;
        });
```

**Ngresource**

```
.factory('Transaction', function($resource){
        return $resource('http://library.app/transactions/:id', {id: '@_id'} , {
            update: {method: 'PUT'},
        });
    });
```

**html block**

```
<ul class="timeline">
                    <li>
                        <div class="timeline-item">
                            <h5 class="timeline-header"></h5>
                            <div class="timeline-body">
                                <ul dir-paginate="transaction in transactions|itemsPerPage:2" class="list-group">
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><small class="text-success">Borrower:</small> {{transaction.lastname}}, {{transaction.firstname}}</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><small class="text-success">Title of Book: {{transaction.title}}</small> </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><small class="text-success">Due:</small> {{transaction.duedate}} </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><small class="text-success">Status:</small> <span class="label label-danger">Pending</span> </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-footer">
                                <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><small>Transact</small></a>
                                <dir-pagination-controls
                                    max-size="3"
                                    direction-links="true"
                                    boundary-links="true" >
                                </dir-pagination-controls>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

**Backend / Laravel 5.1**
**Contoller**

```
public function index() {

   $transactions = DB::table('transactions')
                    ->join('books', 'transactions.book_id', '=', 'books.id')
                    ->join('lenders', 'transactions.lender_id', '=', 'lenders.lenderID' )
                    ->select('transactions.borrowdate', 'transactions.duedate', 'books.title', 'lenders.firstname', 'lenders.lastname')
                    ->get();
                    //dd($transactions);
    return response()->json([
            'msg' => 'Success',
            'transaction' => $transactions
            ]);

}
```

though the query is ok i can't see the data. If anyone or someone has an idea please share it with may.. i appreciate it so much..

Comment: What scope is 
Transaction.get(function(data){
            $scope.transactions = data.transactions;
        });

placed in ? is it in a controller perhaps ?

Comment: yes,, the object should be return. the query is ok

Comment: you didn't answer my question. what's the $scope that this function sits in. 
i don't see an ng-controller on your html. so unless it's hooked up in some other way you might be running on a different scope then the one you think.
is it in a controller ?

Comment: yes it is in the controller

Comment: the ng-app and ng-controller is in my header tag block

Comment: good, how does dir-paginate 
know what scope it is referring to  ?

Comment: sorry only ng-app,, by the way im using ui-route, so every page of my app uses different ng controller..sorry for that

Comment: OK so it is hooked up. you should state that in your question so people don't think it's a scope related issue. or might see one in how it is hooked up.  
does it work with ng-repeat . just throw that data in there to see it is arriving where you expected ?

Comment: here is my state that connected to that page

Comment: url: '/books',
      views: {
       'navigator': {templateUrl: '../partial/navigator.html'},
       '': {templateUrl: '../partial/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DisplayController'}}

Comment: it seems to be working when simple query is perform, i mean only one model is included, but in this case multiple model it doesn't...

Comment: Iv'e had an issue once when the routeprovider didn't hook up the controller to the scope. and i had to use ng-model on it with a local variable pointing to "this" in order for it to actually obtain the scope.
try putting the controller explicitly on that line with ng-controller just to check it out.

Comment: ok.. thanks for the advice sir

Comment: let us know if you tried it out and you see your data. i came across this issue. sadly i didn't find the tutorial where the author added a $scope.vm = this in the controller and then made an ng-model="vm" on the template.
the controller's is running but it's $scope for some strange reason isn't being hooked up to the template

Comment: no error at all, it responce accordingly, the method request GET 200 ok, hahaha crap. maybe it complicate the other get method, i guess? 'cause in this controller i had two get request with different model in my backend in my case Book and Transaction, is it possible?

Comment: omg, it's like i was talking to myself the all time, sure the get method. good luck to you SIR!

Comment: sorry i get you offend hehehe, i did all your advise but it didn't sir sorry sorry sorry i mean it

Comment: you didn't try the explicit controller. which would actually work btw

Comment: really? how come to mine did not work?

Comment: have you read my comments ? 
I am trying to see if the problem is what i once came across 
you see i described a problem that i think occurs. and I'm trying to get you to try it out, since you asked for help on SO. i don't know why it occurs but i do know that it does as stated in the comments above.

Comment: by a chance, perhaps u've used the ng-model derictives?